# What's wrong with the redirection of Powershell output?

Tags: powershell, redirect, command-line, windows-10, output

I'm writing a simple command/script for monitoring memory usage in Powershell, it looks as follows:

```
PS C:\Temp_Folder> while ($true) {
>> Get-Date
>> TaskList /FI "PID eq 82660" | findstr /I "Prod"
>> Start-Sleep 1 }
```

This command/script shows the results on the prompt, but as I expect a lot of results, I would like to output to a file, so this is what I did (see [this official URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.4)):

```
PS C:\Temp_Folder> while ($true) {
>> Get-Date
>> TaskList /FI "PID eq 82660" | findstr /I "Prod"
>> Start-Sleep 1 } 2>&1 >>.\Geheugen.txt
```

However, this seems not to work:

```
PS C:\Temp_Folder> dir Geheugen.txt
dir : Cannot find path 'C:\Temp_Folder\Geheugen.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ dir Geheugen.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Temp_Folder\Geheugen.txt:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I already tried with and without error redirection (`2>&1` and using append and overwrite (`>>` and `>`)), but no luck.
I know for a fact that the command/script is working: I see the results on the prompt.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit after some investigation:**
Apparently, there is an `Out-File` command, which should be used as follows:

```
PS C:\Temp_Folder> while ($true) {
>> Get-Date
>> TaskList /FI "PID eq 82660" | findstr /I "Prod"
>> Start-Sleep 1 } 2>&1 | Out-File -FilePath .\Geheugen.txt
```

This is quite confusing:
In DOS (Windows commandline), redirection to a file can always be done, using the standard redirection operators `>` and `>>`. Apparently those operators are foreseen in Windows Powershell too, but **sometimes** they don't work. Does anybody have an exact description of that *sometimes*?

**Extra test:**
The `Out-File` seems not to be working, as you can see:

```
 while ($true) {
>> Get-Date
>> TaskList /FI "PID eq 4240" | findstr /I "Prod"
>> Start-Sleep 1 } | Out-file -FilePath .\Prod_Server_Monitoring.txt
```

I get following error message:

```
At line:4 char:17
+ Start-Sleep 1 } | Out-file -FilePath .\Prod_Server_Monitoring.tx ...
+                 ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird. On my 7.4.0 your first example does not returns any error, using your exact same code.

It also does not write the file but that's normal: you are attempting to write the success and error streams of the `while` ITSELF, not of the CONTENTS of the code it runs.

You'd EITHER need to enclose the whole `while(){}` in a variable (es:`$(while{}) >> 'file.txt'`) or a scriptblock (es: `& { while(){} } >> 'file.txt'`

If you want to keep the terminal output, though, you might need to play with `Tee-Object`.

**Edit from question author:**
I've put the while-loop inside a variable and that solves the issue indeed:

```
$(while ($true) { 
...
}) >>.\Prod_Server_Monitoring.txt
```

Comment: My first example does not yield any error too, but while checking the output file, it seems not to be present. As for the streams: there indeed seem to be different streams in Powershell. Quite interesting, thanks, but I don't understand the difference between success stream and content stream you mentioned. I've embedded the while-loop inside a variable, as you proposed, and that indeed writes the output to my outputfile. URL about the streams: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.4#redirectable-output-streams

Answer (score 1):

You can't add `| Out-File` after while loop, because loop not return any value. You need to that after specific command. Add also -Append flag to not overwrite your file

```
while ($true) {
    Get-Date
    TaskList /FI "PID eq 4240" | findstr /I "Prod" | Out-File 
    .\Prod_Server_Monitoring.txt -Append
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```

Comment: You answer is correct indeed, but there's a catch: in my example I'm running three commands: `Get-Date`, `TaskList` and `Start-Sleep`, and only two out of the three generate output, which should be sent to the output file (meaning that also after the `Get-Date` an `Out-File` needs to be added). However, imagine that my script would consist of tens of commands, what should be done in order to avoid putting an `Out-File` after every single command?

Comment: You have some solutions. First: you can create script block and execute it with redirection
```
$myscriptblock = {
    Get-Date
    TaskList /FI "PID eq 4240" | findstr /I "Prod" | Out-File 
    .\Prod_Server_Monitoring.txt -Append
    Start-Sleep 1
}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $myscriptblock | Out-File "d:\Prod_Server_Monitoring.txt"
```

Comment: Other solution is to use Transcript--- 

Start-Transcript -path "d:\Prod_Server_Monitoring.txt" -append
while ($true) {
trap {Stop-Transcript; break}
Get-Date
TaskList /FI "PID eq 4240" | findstr /I "Prod" 
Start-Sleep 1
}
Stop-Transcript

---But Transcript add you header in file, which you propably don't want